# Persian name for the al-mi'rāj (one-horned rabbit)

Tags: mythical-creatures, persian

The al-mi'rāj is a creature of Persian myth, which resembles a one-horned rabbit. Despite being a Persian myth, most sources seem to have been written in Arabic, hence the Arabic name(s), but what is the creature called in the Persian language?

Comment: Just pointing out that the [jackalope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackalope) has two horns.

Comment: Probably just "ٱلْمِعْرَاج" pronounced in Persian.

Comment: If so, how does the pronunciation differ? Would it affect the Latin transcription?